# Workaround for a Visual studio 2005 c++ inheritance bug

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class, visual-c++-2005

The following code does not compile in Visual Studio 2005:

```
class OriginalClass
{
public:
    class Delegate
    {
        virtual void original_func()=0;
    };
};

class BaseClass
    :public OriginalClass::Delegate //  Problem line 1
{
public:
    class Delegate
    {
        virtual void base_func(int x) = 0;
    };

    void original_func()override{}  //  Problem line 2
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass::Delegate
{
public:
    virtual void base_func(int x) override {};
};

int main ()
{
    DerivedClass derived_object;

    derived_object.base_func(10);
}
```

The build output is:

```
1>inherit\main.cpp(26) : error C3668: 'DerivedClass::base_func' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
1>inherit\main.cpp(32) : error C2259: 'DerivedClass' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>        due to following members:
1>        'void OriginalClass::Delegate::original_func(void)' : is abstract
1>        inherit\main.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'OriginalClass::Delegate::original_func'
```

If I comment out the lines marked *Problem line 1* and *Problem line 2* it builds OK. So, the use of **override** is not a problem, nor is inheriting from the nested class. It seems to have difficulty in figuring out which Delegate class is the correct one to use.

This problem does not exist in VC2008.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this? Besides the obvious: upgrade to a modern compiler!

Also, I would appreciate it if anyone can point to any documentation of the bug (if it is a bug).

**Edit:**
@Anonymous Coward suggested using typedefs, it will compile if the OriginalClass is changed to the following:

```
class OriginalClass
{
public:
    class Delegate_t
    {
        virtual void original_func()=0;
    };
    typedef Delegate_t Delegate;
};
```

Comment: The reason you cannot use a different compiler is what exactly?  The error itself is pretty clear what the compiler has a problem with, you have any other proof, this is a compiler bug, and simply not the fact the compiler is missing this ability?

Comment: @Ramhound The reason that I need to stick with 2005 is that I need to support an old wince device, for which I only have a 2005 SDK. I do not know if it is a bug, but I still need to get this code to compile somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a name resolution problem indeed. It compiles when using typedefs:

```
class OriginalClass {
    // class Delegate { ... };
    typedef Delegate delegate_t;
};

class BaseClass : public OriginalClass::delegate_t {
    // class Delegate { ... };
    typedef Delegate delegate_t;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass::delegate_t {
    // ...
};
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you. You only need to change the name of OriginalClass::Delegate and typedef that to get it to work.